# How to send arraylist of custom object from server to client in proper way?

Tags: java, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

It might be newbie question but I just started my adventure with sockets.

So I have Server and Client class, client can add services to the server and get services from server. I implemented adding functionality and it works properly but I have problem with sending client serviceList back to him. When I run program and use getAllServices method nothing happens, program waits forever for something, no errors - nothing.

Here's my code:

```
  //serverSide code

  input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
  output= new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

  //same input and output declaration on client side

 private void sendClientList() throws IOException{
   List <ServerHandler> clientList=server.getClients();
   int size=clientList.size();
   output.println(size);
   output.flush();
   for(ServerHandler client: clientList){
    output.println(client.getLogin());
    output.flush();
  }
 }

private void getAllServices()throws IOException{
 List <ServerHandler> clientList=server.getClients();
 sendClientList();
 int serviceListSize=0;
 for(ServerHandler client: clientList){
   List<Service> serviceList=getServiceList();
   serviceListSize=serviceList.size();
   output.println(serviceListSize);
   output.flush();
   for(Service service: serviceList){
     output.println(service.getName());
     output.flush();
     output.println(service.getOwner());
     output.flush();
     output.println(service.getAvailable());
     output.flush();
     output.println(service.getData());
     output.flush();
   }
 }
}

 //client side code

 private List <String> getClientsFromServer() throws IOException{
  int getSize=0; //clientList size
  getSize=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
  for(int i=0;i<getSize;i++){
    String name=input.readLine();
    clientList.add(name);
  }
  return clientList;
 } 


private void getAllServices()throws IOException{
  List<String> clientList=getClientsFromServer();
  int serviceListSize=0;
  for(String client: clientList){
    serviceListSize=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
    for(int i=0;i<serviceListSize;i++)
    {
      String name=input.readLine();
      String owner=input.readLine();
      String available=input.readLine();
      String data=input.readLine();
      serviceList.add(new Service(name,owner,available,data));
    }
 }
  for(String client: clientList){
    for(Service service: serviceList){
      System.out.println(service.getService());
    }
  }
}
```

I know there is something like ObjectInputStream and ObjectOutputStream but I wanted to try sending Service object fields by fields and I would like to know what is my mistake here. Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: Consider converting the data to JSON for the transfer

Comment: Are you sure you are communicating? One side must write while the other reads, maybe you are trying to read first from both sides

Comment: read from both sides? Server don't read anything in this method he just sents serviceList fields to the client.

Comment: Where is `getServiceList()` defined?